# AOSP method names endings

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions, android-source

I'm reading code in the Android Open Source Project, and I see methods with method names that have funny endings, like this:
addSharedUserLPw() (in com.android.server.pm.Settings) 
installPackageLI() (in com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService)

I'm sure the LPw and LI etc. have meanings, I'm just not sure how to figure them out. Can anyone provide any more information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, [Initial commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/54b6cfa9a9e5b861a9930af873580d6dc20f773c/services/java/com/android/server/PackageManagerService.java) of `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/PackageManagerService.java` mentions **LI** and **LP** as follows:

```
177. // Lock for state used when installing and doing other long running
178. // operations. Methods that must be called with this lock held have
179. // the prefix "LI".

...

196. // Keys are String (package name), values are Package. This also serves
197. // as the lock for the global state. Methods that must be called with
198. // this lock held have the prefix "LP".
```